# I'm trying to get render_template to work on my website, having trouble

Tags: python, .htaccess, flask

It's my "first day" at this, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to get render_template to work so I can use Python to work over html using the program Flask. I've gone through the tutorials, but they only tell me how to execute the code through terminal, and only then by calling Python explicitly. I've made the three files (routes.py, layout, and home) I need to get the functionality to work and put them in the (app folder, template folder in app, template folder in app). I then put the app folder in the public_html file on my server.

When I go to the "mywebpage"/app/template/home.html address I get the html file as originally written without the {{}} variables replaced. Completely stumped. I don't know if I have to explicitly call the routes.py file explicitly in an html file, whether I have to tell DirectoryIndex in .htaccess to look for it, or if the server should find it in the app folder by itself. But basically I know routes.py calls the other files, but I don't know how routes.py gets called.

Here is my code:

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)      

@app.route('mywebsite')
def home():
   user = {'nickname': 'Miguel'}  # fake user
   return render_template('home.html', user = user)

'''if __name__ == '__main__':'''
app.run(debug=True)
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="jumbo">
    <h2>Welcome to the Flask app<h2>
    <h3>This is the home page for the Flask app<h3>
  </div>
  <body>
      <p> Hello, {{user.nickname}} </p>
   </body>
{% endblock %}
```

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask App</title>    
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">Flask App</h1>
      </div>
    </header> 

    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Finally, be nice. I've done everything I can think of to get to this point.

EDIT: This website:

http://melvin0008.github.io/blog/build-a-redditapi-using-python/

says that @app.route('/pants') should make mywebsite.com/pants display the rendered template. I've tried that with my route.py document both in the root public_html folder and in the app folder. Neither worked. website.com/pants isn't seen by my server.

Comment: What URL do you write in the browser?

Comment: It sounds like your placing these files on a server and expecting Apache to just serve them (similar to how PHP works). This isn't how Flask (or Python in general) works. You need to run the application, typically through a WSGI server. In the case of Apache, mod_wsgi is generally what you're looking for. See the [docs about deploying Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/) for more information.

Comment: dirn - Yes! I thought you are supposed to run it like an html or php file, where you just dump it into the public_html folder and it's good to go. I'll look into the WSGI server thing, but if anyone has other "idiot's guides" to making one I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

When running a Flask server (in debug, in that case) you should take the URL written in the terminal, probably `localhost:8080` and append to it the route you want to evoke.

For that matter, in order to see the webpage you built you should enter in the browser `localhost:8080/mywebsite` when `localhost:8080` is your server URL.

I recommend you change the route name to `/`, like that:
Instead of:
`@app.route('mywebsite')`
Write this:
`@app.route('/')`

Than you will get your home page at `localhost:8080/`

Comment: I'm not sure this solves my problem. I want this to go on my website so it's publicly accessible, not just be visible to me on the localhost. Also, see my recent edit.

Comment: Than you should run the server with `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` this will expose your server to the network. Remember to turn debug off when going to production. Google for Flask production best practices. If you want your website to be public in the internet than you should get a hosting service, upload your application and buy a domain name.

Comment: Ummm....I have a domain name. I also tried turning host=0.0.0.0 and going to my website. Where is the modified template (at what url)? You haven't solved my problem.

Comment: You need to read a little about deploying a flask server. Why don't you tell us what is the exact process you are trying that doesn't work. Action by action.

Answer (score 0):

Doron is correct. When you run your application is should tell you that it is running on the port you specify. You can then go to your localhost:xxxx/mywebsite and view it.

for example this set up will return the hello.html file when I go to localhost:1200/hello

```
@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return render_template("hello.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=1200, debug=True)
```

As far as running it so that other people can see it you will need a server will a dedicated IP address and an Apache server so that you can launch the application, or if you want you can use heroku for free.

Comment: I don't think I understood your answer. I don't want to go to localhost - I want this displayed on my website; I thought I said that above. I have a website with a host domain (so I guess I have a server - did you mean I needed a special server?) I think I should be able to launch the application from my webhost. Is an Apache server something special - I thought Apache was the application that read .htaccess and like files. I'm not sure Apache should apply here. Basically, of what you wrote, I don't think I understood anything. Sorry :/

Comment: Don't worry I think I misunderstood your question. If you were to run the flask program you wrote on the server that your website is on you could access it. However to get it to run on port 80 (the http port) you would have to run it through apache or some other server. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your replies to the other answers I think you've had a fundamental misunderstanding of how Flask projects are deployed.

Unlike other languages like PHP or just standard HTML, you can't just call a python file or path from within your browser, you need to start the server application on the remote server.

If you're using shared webhosting this probably won't be possible.

Usually when I develop flask apps I start an EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services and deploy it all manually, or use the Elastic Beanstalk service they offer.

You may also find shared webhosts that allow you to deploy flask apps.